# WebDriverException: Message: [(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/proxy.js] with Selenium GeckoDriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, marionette, geckodriver

I am downloading multiple reports from a website. Each report has its own URL. Some URLs are loading fine without a problem.

But there is one URL that produces the following error. All URLs have the same pattern except for query parameter. If I open the URL on my browser it works fine.

I am using Selenium and the Firefox Driver. 
[image]

Below is my code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
firefox_options = Options()
#firefox_options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, executable_path=firefox_driver_location)



logged_in = "no"
for query in sa360_query_array:
    print("query being processed is " + query )
    if  "270348" in query or "269756" in query:
        wait_time = 300
    else:
        wait_time = 15
    driver.get(query)
    print("Page wait time is " + str(wait_time))
    driver.implicitly_wait(300000)
    #print(driver.page_source)
    if logged_in !="yes":
        google_login(query,email_login,email_password) #This function logs into google account
        print("Sleeping 200 seconds")
        time.sleep(200)

    logged_in = "yes"

    #time.sleep(200)
    print("reading HTML")
    #print(driver.page_source)
    read_web = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)#The error occurs on this line
```

What is that error referring too?

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace in text format.

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Message: [Exception...  "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/proxy.js :: sendReply_ :: line 276"  data: no]
```

...implies that the **Marionette** threw an error while attempting to read/store/copy the `page_source()`.

The relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) / [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However it seems the issue is with the fact that the `page_source()` is emencely huge/large which exceeds the max value of the max value **Marionette** can handle. Possibly it's a much bigger `string` you're dealing with.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be to avoid passing the `page_source()` to the variable and print it to find out where the actual issue lies.

```
print(driver.page_source)
```

Another aspect to look after would be `pd.read_html()` which I am quite not sure.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussion in:

- [WebDriverException: Message: Exception… “Failure” nsresult: “0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)” while saving a large html file using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886298/webdriverexception-message-exception-failure-nsresult-0x80004005-ns-e/57887157#57887157)

---

### Outro

Documentation links:

- [WebDriver:TakeScreenshot generates error when web page has a big height](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1306)
- [WebDriver:TakeScreenshot fails in canvas "scale()" for huge web pages](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1471265)
- [Exception NS_ERROR_FAILURE in ctx.scale() if width or height is greater than 32767](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1485730)
- [event.synthesizeMouseAtPoint() should only call nsIDOMWindowUtils.sendMouseEvent() if there is a valid window handle](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1471538)

Comment: It is a very long page compared to the others. Let me try printing out the page source and see what I can discover

Comment: @Quinnystar27 _...It is a very long page compared to the others..._ is exactly what I emphasized  as _**Possibly it's a much bigger string you're dealing with**_ within my answer.