# "Component not initialized" nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)" error with Selenium GeckoDriver and Mozilla

Tags: selenium, mozilla, geckodriver, webdriverwait, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to execute my code in Firefox, sometimes it works but majority of time i get exception as:

```
[Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/dom.js :: addEventListener :: line 67"  data: no]
```

Its happening from last week, previously it was working fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

[NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Errors#General_Errors) resembles an attempt which was made to use a component or object which has not yet been initialized. These components usually provide an initialization method, often called `Init` which must be called before any other methods which are being used.

However, this error message...

```
[Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/dom.js :: addEventListener :: line 67"  data: no]
```

...implies that the **Marionette** threw an error while invoking `addEventListener` as defined in **`dom.js`**

Your code trials and the relevant [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However it seems the `addEventListener` was invoked too early even before the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) was completely rendered. To be more specific `addEventListener` was invoked even before the *Browser Client* (i.e. the Web Browser) have attained `'document.readyState'` equal to `"complete"`. Generally once this condition is fulfilled [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) performs the next line of code.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be to before you try to interact with any of the element on a fresh loaded webpage you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for either of the following [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions):

- [`title_is(title)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_is)
- [`title_contains(title)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains)

### An example

- *Python*:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.title_contains("Stack"))
    print("Page Title is : "+driver.title)
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
    ```
- *Java*:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Stack"));
    System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    Page Title is : Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
    ```

---

### Additional Considerations

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u221**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.25.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.25.0) level.
- Ensure that the version of the binaries you are using are compatable.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v69.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [WebDriverException: Message: Exception… “Failure” nsresult: “0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)” while saving a large html file using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886298/webdriverexception-message-exception-failure-nsresult-0x80004005-ns-er/57887157#57887157)
- [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception… “Component not initialized” error using GeckoDriver and Tor browser with Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563686/org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-exception-component-not-initialized/62646245#62646245)

---

### Outro

[Occur the 'NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED' when switching the window to bottom dock.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1484595)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're suffering from [Geckodriver Issue 1263](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1263), you can try the following workarounds:

1. Update Selenium client library to the latest stable which is [3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) as of now, it's better to use package management system like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org) as update of dependencies libraries might be required. If you're not using Java check out [Web - Desktop and Mobile Browsers](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium) article for code examples for different Selenium client languages like JavaScript, Python, C#, etc.
2. Make sure to use the latest version of [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
3. Make sure to use the latest version of [Geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

If you will be still experiencing problems you can consider raising a [new issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues) in the Geckodriver project, be prepared to provide as much information as possible (the same applies to next questions here if any)

Answer (score 0):

On my case, some configs were wrong. I was trying to block pop-up downloads, but something went wrong.Here is the code that I had to remove, and it worked (on this specific case):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();

profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Temp");
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv");
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.panel.shown", false);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ELEMENT_SCROLL_BEHAVIOR, 1);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```