# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception... "Component not initialized" error using GeckoDriver and Tor browser with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, tor

I tried to run Selenium with Tor Browser but get an error.
When i start my code, the Tor Browser opens and calls the url https://www.trash-mail.com/adresse-erstellen/ correctly but instead of making the last command with "sendKeys" this error occurres:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/modal.js :: get window :: line 143"  data: no]
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'MacBook-Pro.local', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '14.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 68.9.0, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200407010101, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.25.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 21229, moz:profile: /var/folders/5s/9gmx38s53zl..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 18.7.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: d12a4cf5-9c6f-1549-9dc4-c272dcc7aaee
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=#form-password-new1}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:420)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:431)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.eviltester.webdriver.Connection.open(Connection:28)
```

**Here is my code so far:**

```
package com.eviltester.webdriver;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class Connection {

    private static final String macPath = "/Users/Admin/Documents/Projekte/workspace/project1/webdriver/geckodriver";
    private static final String torPath = "/Users/Admin/Documents/Projekte/workspace/project1/webdriver/tor";
    private static final String torFirefox = "/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox";
    private static final String torProfile ="/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/Resources/TorBrowser/Tor";
    
    private FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    
    public Connection() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", macPath);
    }
    
    public void open() {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(new File(torProfile));
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torFirefox));
        
        options.setBinary(binary);
        options.setProfile(profile);
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.trash-mail.com/adresse-erstellen/");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#form-postbox-new"))).sendKeys("testmail123");

    }
}
```

**Would be nice if someone could help me with my problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: [Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/modal.js :: get window :: line 143"  data: no]
```

...implies that that the Marionette threw an error while attempting to interacting with the desired element.

---

It seems the `get window` was invoked too early even before the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) was completely rendered. To be more specific `addEventListener` was invoked even before the *Browser Client* (i.e. the Web Browser) have attained `'document.readyState'` equal to `"complete"`. Generally once this condition is fulfilled [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) performs the next line of code.

---

### Solution

A quick solution will be to before you try to interact with any of the element on a fresh loaded webpage instead of [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as `presenceOfElementLocated` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()`  and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *id*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("form-postbox-new"))).sendKeys("testmail123");
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#form-postbox-new"))).sendKeys("testmail123");
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='form-postbox-new']"))).sendKeys("testmail123");
  ```

---

### Additional Considerations

Ensure that:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

> **Note**: [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) have issues with [Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100247/an-illegal-reflective-access-operation-has-occurred-while-executing-automated-te/58132830#58132830), [Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876955/unable-to-import-org-openqa-selenium-webdriver-using-selenium-and-java-11/54880228#54880228) and [Java 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531018/does-selenium-v3-141-support-java-13).

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current _Firefox v77.0.1 _ levels.
- Ensure that the version of the binaries you are using are compatable.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for **non-root** users.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [“Component not initialized” nsresult: “0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)” error with Selenium GeckoDriver and Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57950661/component-not-initialized-nsresult-0xc1f30001-ns-error-not-initialized-er/57953202#57953202)
- [WebDriverException: Message: Exception… “Failure” nsresult: “0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)” while saving a large html file using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886298/webdriverexception-message-exception-failure-nsresult-0x80004005-ns-er/57887157#57887157)

---

### Outro

[Occur the 'NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED' when switching the window to bottom dock.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1484595)

Answer (score 0):

Which Geckodriver version do you use? I am asking because there is an issue with the firefox driver version < 69: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1477977, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1690. I had the same error but it occurred when I tried to interact with modal windows, not when calling sendKeys.

If possible, try to update the version of the driver and see if the problem persists.